# How i can change CCLabelBMFont text color

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

How i can change CCLabelBMFont text color.

```
highScoreLabel = [CCLabelBMFont  labelWithString:highScore fntFile:@"markerFelt.fnt"];
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the color property, for example:

```
highScoreLabel.color = ccc3(240, 40, 40);
```

This would only work well if the original color was white.

Comment: what do you mean by original color

Comment: i just create a label now i want to change its color. I try this one code but it is not working for me. it turn the text color to black

Comment: If you don't do anything. What color is the label?

Comment: its blue. because font png file has blue color. Just add the png file of custom font in the question

Comment: the font characters need to be white if changing the color property should result in the actual color. Otherwise it's the color property's color plus the font character's color (blue). Depending on that color, you'll get quite different colors.